# list.item(0) vs list[0]

Tags: javascript, performance

`document.getElementsByTagName('a').item(0)`

and

`document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]`

will return the same result...

Is the former faster than the latter?

Comment: No mater the result, it won't mater. If you are using Javascript (on a Web browser) for performance you are using the wrong language. You should focus on other consideration, such as readability.

Comment: @HoLyVieR just a question that was sparked by a blog post. I'd figure the difference is minimal.

Comment: @Alexandre I know, but those kind of "optimization" aren't needed at all in 99,999% of the situation if not 100%. If you want to get better code, you should focus more on other aspect of the code.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: Your claim that performance does not matter at all in Javascript is just as myopic as trying to implement real-time missile control systems in the browser. The truth is that even in a "high-performance" language like C, readability is a huge concern. Conversely, even in a relatively luxurious environment like a Javascript Web app, you should still take reasonable measures not to waste your users' system resources. This doesn't mean ignoring readability, but, say, if a loop is pinning the CPU, you might want to memoize instead of call an expensive function millions of times a second.

Comment: @Chuck You claim thing I haven't said. Don't over analyze what people say. Seriously this is a thousand miles from what I have said.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: You said, "No matter the result, it won't matter." To make this claim without qualification implies that performance does not matter in Javascript. Because if performance matters, then it certainly does matter if one equivalent operation performs significantly faster than another.

Comment: @Chuck I did clarify in the comments rigth after. This kind of optimization is called micro-optimization, in Javascript micro-optimization is useless in nearly all the situation. Mainly, because the result will vary from a browser to an other and it's never significant.

Comment: @holyvier from the observations here, the performance difference is around 30%. are you going to claim reducing your run time by 1/3 is a micro-optimization?

Comment: @lincolnk Are you calling this 1 million time in your script ? I seriously doubt it and even if you were calling it 1 millions times (wich is an insane amount of call), the difference would be of around 200 ms (1/5 of seconds). 200 ms isn't really noticable from a user point of view.

Comment: @holyvier maybe I am. You have no idea where I or anyone else may be applying this. Your statement is naive. As noted for Felix's simple demo, the different in processing time in IE8 (which is all I get at work) is on the order of 3 seconds.

Comment: @lincolnk If you are realying on micro-optmization for your code to run smoothly, this should ring a bell. You are doing something else wrong. Also, I'd also like to quote myself again "the result will vary from a browser to an other". If you look at the result from Danielle it's the exact opposite of the Felix's one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selfmade performance test: http://jsfiddle.net/438jh/2/

The difference seems to be negligible. The second method performs better in most case, but if you have a look on how often the loop is performed it does not really matter.

**Chrome:**

1. method: ~260ms
2. method: ~170ms

Comment: Trying your jsFiddle in Firefox 3.6.6, I get about 250 for the first method and 475 for the second.

Comment: results in ie8: test1: 5000+ test2: ~2000. I even have to punch "no" when IE asks me to stop running scripts during test 2 and it's still significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

item function is a member of `NodeList` DOM object. `NodeLists` are array-like but they are not real arrays (e.g.: they are live, read-only, lack of array functions).

The performance difference should be negligible.

Comment: Yeap, I read this before posting... http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/

Comment: i suggest that you focus on more important optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

For a more practical example, this technique has the best performance.  Look at work by Nicholas Zakas, YAHOO! for more examples:

```
var cachedDOMquery = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.getElementsByTagName('a')),
i = cachedDOMquery.length,
item;
while(i--){
    item = cachedDOMquery[i];
    alert(item.href);
}
```