# Javascript item method of Select

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var x=document.getElementById("mySelect");
alert(x.options.item(1).text);
alert(x.options[1].text);
```

Here we are getting the text of option.
What is the difference between

```
x.options.item(1).text
```

and

```
x.options[1].text
```

as both are yielding same result.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824629/list-item0-vs-list0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SELECT element has a collection of options.

When you do options[i] you're actually accessing collection directly (e.g. array).

When you do options.item(i) you're accessing same thing but through API.

Second way is recommended because if underlying implementation of collection changes you might get exceptions. That's why there is an API.

API spec:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection

Answer (score 1):

The `options collection` returns a `collection` of all the `options` in a dropdown list.

```
x.options.item(index)       //Returns the element from the collection with the specified index

x.options[index]            // will returns element from collection with specified collection .index is an integer specifies the element to retrieve (starts at 0)
```

So `.text` will return the same in both the cases

Here is a list of methods of collection Select options Collection

```
[index]                 An integer that specifies the element to retrieve (starts at 0)
[add(element[,index])]  Adds an option element into the collection at the specified index. If no index is specified, it inserts the option element at the end of the collection
item(index)             Returns the element from the collection with the specified index
namedItem(name)         Returns the element from the collection with the specified name (name or id attribute)
remove(index)           Removes the element with the specified index from the collection
```

Answer (score 0):

The `options` object here is actually an [`OptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection) instance which inherits from [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection); as such it exposes a few properties and methods, such as:

- `length`
- `item(index)`
- `namedItem(name)`

Besides that it can also be dereferenced as an array, i.e. `options[i]` is the same as `options.item(i)`. The same trick can be applied to methods like [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) and friends.